# Magento: Custom email error default template

Tags: php, magento, email-validation

I made email blacklist module for registration new customers. it is necessary for me if the new email address match with a blacklist there was a return on the registration page to a default template but to my message. on a screenshot a default template, instead of the message from it I want to write: email is blacklisted.
please help.

```
public function customerEmailBlackList($observer)
{
    $helper = Mage::helper('emailblacklist');
    if (!$helper->getEnabled()) {
        return;
    }
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $email = $customer->getEmail();             
    $emailblacklist = $helper->getEmailblacklist();
    // $session_data = unserialize($emailblacklist);
    // echo $email;
    // var_dump($session_data);
    if (substr_count($emailblacklist, $email) > 0) {
        echo "blacklisted";
    }
    // throw new exception('blah-blah-blah');   
    // die;
    }
```

Screenshoot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yUQs.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you corrcet, you wanted to change the error message what is appearing, right?
You can do this with this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('Email is blacklisted');
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! works perfect! but still need stay on this page, i add throw new exception(); See screenshoot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NfbUg.jpg (and in addition have Cannot save the customer.) - i need to remove it. or better good way to stay on account creating page?

Comment: Solved. Mage::throwException('Email is blacklisted') works perfect. this right method by the way?

Comment: Yes, that the right method, that will stop the saving process!